List sharepoint related field
enter image description here
enter image description here
Hello,
I'm working on a sharepoint list and I'd like the user to select an "lot impliqué" and then be offered only the "Chantier" associated with that lot, as shown in the photo, and not ALL the "Chantier" in the list.
I tried linked list but i think it's not the solution
